# How to get multiple commands to run with imap

Tags: vim

I've added the following configuration to my init.vim file (I'm using neovim):

`imap <leader>aa <Esc> :w!<CR>`

My `<leader>` has been mapped to space.

The goal is to hit SPC aa when in insert mode and I will exit insert mode and then force write the file.

This [documentation](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)) makes it seem like having a sequence of commands should work just fine with imap. I have other multicommand shortcuts in my init.vim that work just fine too, for example `nnoremap <leader>so :source $MYVIMRC<CR>`.

When I execute the `imap <leader>aa <Esc> :w!<CR>` shortcut all that happens is that I exit insert mode. The changes are not forced written. This implies that only `<ESC>` is being executed.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Try using `:inoremap`. That space between `<Esc>` and `:w!` is superfluous (it will actually move the cursor right, or as you have configured leader to be space, may trigger a `<Leader>:` mapping if you have any).

Comment: Remove the space. Try just the `imap <leader>aa <Esc>:w!<CR>`

Comment: If no custom mapping is invoked, and the space therefore is used as the built-in normal mode movement, and you're triggering the mapping at the end of the buffer, that motion will fail (with a beep), and any further mapping keys (i.e. the `:w!`) will be aborted. That could explain the problem if you trigger at the end of the buffer.

Comment: On a side note, you should avoid mappings starting with `<leader>`/`<space>` in insert mode. Because of that, every time you'll hit `<space>`, you'll see a delay before the regular space you'll want to type being displayed. Insert mode mappings triggered by displayable keys should be considered to only modify what is displayed based on the context. Triggering actions has less undesired side effects when the leading key is not something "visible" (CTRL+smthg, ALT+smthg, F42...)

Comment: @IngoKarkat and @ZabojCampula, you were both exactly right! Once I removed the space, the mapping worked perfectly. 

Based on @LucHermitte's great point, I ended up changing the mapping to `imap <C-l> <Esc>:w!<CR>`.

Thanks y'all for the help with this one :)

Comment: Also, apologies for the delayed follow up on this. This was my first question on Stack Overflow and I was expecting to get email notifications when there was activity on this question but that didn't happen. (I'm looking into enabling email notifications now).

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER FOUND**

This mapping:

`imap <leader>aa <Esc> :w!<CR>`

will not work because of the space between `<Esc>` and `:w!<CR>`. If you remove the space, it will work. So the mapping:

`imap <leader>aa <Esc>:w!<CR>`

will work.

Comment: Please use inoremap!